# PostgreSQL: Joining Tables Based on Searched Concatenated Strings

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, join

I'm not sure how to write a join clause that takes a value from table 1, then searches a string in table 2 to see if they match. Sound confusing?

Here's the actual example I'm working with.

**Table 1**

```
Customer_Id   Concat_Phone_Numbers
1                     8888888888;1111111111
```

**Table 2**

```
Caller         Callee      Calldate
1111111111     3333333333  1/1/1900
```

I want to create a table that looks like this:

**Desired Table**

```
Customer_Id  Calldate
1            1/1/1900
```

I'm lost when it comes to writing the join clause so that the entire list in Table 1's second column is searched for a matching phone number/entry.

Thank you in advance for your help! (PS it's my first time asking a question!)

Edit::

Here's where I'm at now

```
Select 
* 
from table1
left join table2 
on ??????????????????
```

Answer (score 1):

Yuck!  You should fix the data structure.  You really need a table with one row per customer and per phone number.  You'll understand why if you care about performance.

But, if you are stuck with this data model, you can do a join using string and/or array operations.  Here is a method using regular expressions

```
select . . .
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.caller ~ '^' || replace(t1.phone_numbers, ';', '|') || '$' or
        t2.callee ~ '^' || replace(t1.phone_numbers, ';', '|') || '$' ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm using pgAdmin III and it's throwing this error, how do I fit it?         " ERROR:  operator does not exist: text + unknown
LINE 6: ...replace(t1.concatenated_formatted_phones, ';', '|') + '$' or
                                                               ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

ERROR: operator does not exist: text + unknown
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 147"

Comment: @groundfalll . . . Oops, wrong string concatenation operator.